# JasperSoft Studio - How is the best way to to print a period of time (minutes) as hh:mm?

Tags: jasper-reports

I´m not asking how to calculate minutes to hh:mm in java. I´m asking the best way to do it in jaspersoft. Because it´s done and it works.  i´m only interseted in the print part in the report in the format "hh:mm "h""

I'm working in a report that must print the time in hh:mm format. (I´m editing a current production report and I want to do the minnor changes posible).

In BD we have at DateTime (DateTimeOffset) the Start and the End of the event.

This is a summatory of all the events the worker had done in a period of time.

Nowadays the report works getting per row the minutes between end and start. And then make a variable (That is a Sum of all the minutes). I do this with several variables because at the end the time is calculate in base of some checks the user has.

I have one more variable to add this minutes to the total if are checked.

And at the end in the Text Field I print this with :

```
($V{Total_Time}/60)+ ":" 
+ (IF($V{Total_Time}%60 < 10,"0"+$V{Total_Time}%60,$V{Total_Time}%60))
+" h"
```

The type of ***Total_Time*** variable is *Integer*

I´m looking for a best way to do this

Comment: What type of `$V{Total_Time}`? Integer?

Comment: $V{Total_Time} is Integer

Comment: `I´m not asking how to calculate minutes to hh:mm in java. I´m asking the best way to do it in jaspersoft. Because it´s done and it works.` - The JasperReports expression supports Java language. This is why it is a duplicate

Comment: It still does not help the good practices when it comes to implment

Comment: Really? ;) What options did you try (from this dupe post)?

Comment: String.format("%d : %02d h",$V{Total_Time}/60,$V{Total_Time}%60 )

I used this form which is practically the one I was using. And the post has barely oriented me. Your reference to Java is vague and unintuitive when the question is.

It is the best way?

Comment: `It is the best way?` - To use expression on Java? - Yes.

Comment: I have to use this in quite a few different reports. And what I was looking for is whether so much reuse should not use a "user function"

Comment: There is no ready for use built-in function at JasperReports. You have to write something. I think that the best way is to this with Java. You can use *textField* expression or variable expression with pure Java expression. You can call scriptlet if you have already some custom code (library)

Comment: So I will need a library to do a "minute to hh:mm h" formater. And looks like that in this case is to much code for this. 

Also looks like Patter or Pattern Expresion is not a good option for this case.

So Thank You. But I don´t see intuitive what methods works in textfield